# Google Play Service, turn-based multiplayer, error 6000, what is it?

Tags: android, google-play-services

In a currently live game a few of the players get an error 6000 when trying to start a multiplayer game via auto-matching or inviting players.

The problem is that error 6000 is not documented anywhere I can see. Does someone know?

To repeat, for most players there are no problems with multiplayer. Only a small subset are affected. But once an account starts getting error 6000, they can't start games anymore at all. They can receive invitation still however.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this later, error 6000 means

> The user is not allowed to create a new multiplayer game at this time.
>   This could occur if the user has too many outstanding invitations
>   already.

It if from [this reference page](https://developers.google.cn/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesStatusCodes?hl=hi), which for some reason doesn't rank very high when Googling :-)